# Target DIV on one place that gets used on multiple places

Tags: html, css

Take the following HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="sitewidth"></div>
</div>
<div class="sitewidth"></div>
<div id="content" class="sitewidth front-page">
</div>
```

How do I target the 2nd `sitewidth`, without triggering the same effect on the `sitewidth` within `topbar` and the one in the next div?

Note that I do NOT have access to the HTML, I can only use CSS!

Comment: Are these the only two times you use `sitewidth` or is it used elsewhere? Also, is this you **exact** HTML structure?

Comment: `sitewidth` is used on multiple places, also right after this one again. It is, however, the 2nd time it gets used and I think that's how it always is (in other words: as far as I know, nothing gets in between `topbar` and the second `sitewidth`).

Comment: Do you want the CSS to also target the 2cd and 3rd sitewidths?  Or just the 2cd one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this comment

> sitewidth is used on multiple places, also right after this one again.
>   It is, however, the 2nd time it gets used and I think that's how it
>   always is (in other words: as far as I know, nothing gets in between
>   topbar and the second sitewidth

and this structure

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="sitewidth"></div>
</div>
<div class="sitewidth"></div>
```

Then

```
#topbar + .sitewidth {
your styles here
}
```

This will only target the `sitewidth` div that **immediately** follows your `#topbar` **and no others**.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only the one directly after the `#topbar` you could Try:

```
#topbar + .sitewidth {
    //CSS rules here
}
```

here is the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ho2a9wtp/

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```css
:not(#topbar) > .sitewidth {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="sitewidth">not this</div>
</div>
<div class="sitewidth">this</div>
```

Comment: As said in the comments, `sitewidth` returns on other places on the website as well. Your snippet targets all `sitewidth`s that are not in the `topbar` (if I understand correctly?), so it's not usable.

Comment: If your html structure is the one in OP then you can use @Paulie_D answer(Adjacent sibling selectors).